# Default cosine value

Tags: trigonometry, circles

As the cosine is defined as $cos \theta = \frac x r $ where x is the length of opposite line and r is length of hypotenuse how can $cos \theta$ be calculated for values where we do not know the lengths of sides of triangles. ?

Various calculators compute the $cos(1) = .999$ , so is there an implicit value for lengths of opposite and adjacent sides ?

Comment: Make a right-angled triangle with the other angles as $1,89$. Then, make one of either the opposite or adjacent side lengths as $1$. Now see how $\cos 1$ is calculated.

Comment: Suppose you have another right triangle with angle $\theta$, opposite side $x'$ and hypothenuse $r'$. Then it is similar to the other triangle, in particular $\dfrac{x}{r}=\dfrac{x'}{r'}$, so it's irrelevant what “implicit length” you choose.

Comment: @egreg insight I had been missing is that $\theta$ remains constant between right angled triangles if they are proportionally equivalent. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This picture should solve your doubt:

[image]

Say the angle $\widehat{BAC}$ is $\theta$; then
$$
\cos\theta=\frac{b}{r}=\frac{b'}{r'}
$$
where $b=AB$, $b'=AD$, $r=AC$ and $r'=AE$, because the two triangles $ABC$ and $ADE$ are similar right triangles.

So, while one needs an “implicit value” for the length, it's immaterial which one you choose, because the *ratio* will be the same.

In the past, in order to avoid decimal numbers, the length of the hypothenuse was taken to be, say, $100\,000$ and the cosine was defined to be the adjacent leg (no ratio). However, this just complicates formulas, so it became common to use an implicit length of $1$ for the hypothenuse, which is the same as taking the ratio.

Thus, saying that $\cos 1^\circ\approx 0.9998$ means that if the hypothenuse is $1$ (meter, foot, yard, centimeter), then the adjacent leg will be approximately $0.9998$ (in meters, feet, yards, centimeters, whatever unit you chose). If the hypothenuse is $2$, you'd get an adjacent leg approximately $1.9996$.

Answer (score 1):

As

$$\frac xr=\frac{\lambda x}{\lambda r}$$ you can take any value for one of the sides and the other varies in proportion.

The implicit value is always taken to be $1$ for the length of the hypothenuses.

Comment: can you elaborate on $\frac xr=\frac{\lambda x}{\lambda r}$ ? What do the $\lambda$ values represent ? Just knowing the length of the hypothenuses is not sufficient to calculate cosine as also require length of opposite side ?